# error Timed out after 100000ms Selenium ide

Tags: selenium, timeout, selenium-ide

```
 <tr>
        <td>setTimeout</td>
        <td>100000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>https://noc.qa.2klic.io/#/tickets</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>openWindowAndWait</td>
        <td>http://localhost:3000/login</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>openWindowAndWait</td>
        <td>http://localhost:3000/arm</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>openWindowAndWait</td>
        <td>http://localhost:3000/trigger4/td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>openWindowAndWait</td>
        <td>http://localhost:3000/untrigger4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>openWindowAndWait</td>
        <td>http://localhost:3000/disarm</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Above is my `selenium-ide` code to open and wait for page to load.  The test fails and the error is:

> [error] Timed out after 100000ms.

I have tried all the solutions on the internet and cannot resolve this issue.

Comment: If that password is used outside of a protected environment, you might want to be careful about putting passwords in your question. What step does this fail on?

Comment: Every time there is an openWindowAndWait this fails with a timeout error

Comment: Does `http://localhost:3000/login` ever load on whichever machine you're running this test on?

Comment: Yes it does a window opens up and the page loads

Comment: I'm more familiar with `selenium-webdriver` so I might not have the best answers, but does `openWindow` not work for you? Have you tried that instead of `openWindowAndWait`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Selenium-IDE documentation on the `AndWait` commands](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#the-andwait-commands):

> Be aware, if you use an AndWait command for an action that does not trigger a navigation/refresh, your test will fail. This happens because Selenium will reach the AndWait‘s timeout without seeing any navigation or refresh being made, causing Selenium to raise a timeout exception.

In your case, you probably want to use `open`. The `AndWait` is triggered **after** the command. So basically, you navigate to the url, **and then** you're waiting for the page to load or refresh, but it loaded before waiting so now it'll just wait until it times out.

Somewhat related, it looks like you're just opening a bunch of `urls` instead of filling in forms, clicking on login buttons, etc... Consider using commands to interact with the page instead of hopping from `url` to `url` to more accurately represent what a user would be doing. From what I understand this can also trigger the `AndWaits` automatically when necessary so you don't have to worry about that complexity. Depending on how you're writing your tests though, you might use `AndWait`, but it would only be after doing something that loads a new page, like `clickAndWait` on a login button.